# When do we use .$put instead of .put on an angular resource?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Say, I have the following resource:

```
angular.module('app.resources.demo-resource', ['ngResource'])
.service('demoResource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/path', { }, { put: { method: 'PUT' } });
  });
```

and I want to invoke the put request, using promises later.
How do I do it correctly?

`newResource.$put().then(...)` or `newResource.put().then(...)`?
Does both variants exist and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a "non-GET" action (basically, one with a method that has a request body: PUT, POST, PATCH), `ngResource` will automatically create corresponding actions/methods on every instance of that resource (prefixed by `$`). This is just for convenience.

Basically, you have two ways to call such an action:

```
<Resource>.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
```

or

```
<instance>.$action([parameters], [success], [error])
```

The benefit of the latter is that you don't need to specify the `postData` (it's the `<instance>` object that acts as the data).

Answer (score 0):

With promises: (To the answer of @ExpertSystem)

```
<Resource>.action([parameters], postData).$promise
```

or

```
<instance>.$action([parameters])
```

is automatically a promise. The first approach looks more stable in practice. (Angular resolved an instance to the wrong resource after I did `_.extend({}, resource)`)